# Some apps scale is rediculous, while others are fine

Tags: 20.04, firefox, scaling

This thing has been bothering for quite some time.
So some apps, firefox, discord are scaled up.
Other apps, pycharm, vs code are just fine.
See the image below.
I hope you guys could help me, it has been days I am working on this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Settings > Displays > 100%  (to attempt to reset scaling); if you have "Fractional scaling" set to anything else than "Off" - you might try to set it off for the time being.

Comment: That does not work

Comment: No difference at all?

Comment: I updated the image after I set Fractional scaling off. No change

Comment: How about the settings under "universal Access" - anything strange there?

Comment: Firefox menu: Settings, Zoom? If nothing: I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Another thing I see is that, it is not only firefox, but discord scaled too. While vs code, pycharm, android studios are just fine

Comment: Something common to both these then. `apt-rdepends` shows package dependencies; might one route here be to diff the outputs for firefox and discord - I have not tried such things (and will not install discord).

Comment: ```bash: apt-rdepends: command not found```

Comment: apt-rdepends has to be installed, yes. `CTRL`-`0` (Zero) resets zoom level in firefox at least; try that?  (sudo apt install apt-rdepends)

Comment: Hmm still nothing

Comment: now; the above should cover the basics. I have no more...

Comment: Thank you for your time though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Temporarily create a new account. Does it happen there?

Comment: I think you have found the cause, with the test user it did not occur. However, what should I do to fix this on my default user?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually this command solved my issue
`dconf reset -f /`