# Menus, fonts, buttons really small in some apps on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: display, interface, scaling

In Ubuntu 22.04 (fully updated as of this post), in *some* applications, the menus, fonts, and buttons appear really tiny. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make these readable / larger / consistent with other "working" apps?

Examples of apps with "tiny" GUI:

- RealVNC Viewer
- TigerVNC Viewer
- GIMP

Examples of apps that work fine:

- Any stock app, e.g. terminal, gnome-control-center, etc.
- JetBrains IDEs (Clion, PyCharm, etc.)
- Sublime text editor
- Chrome & Firefox browsers
- cmake-gui
- Thunderbird

System setup:

- Screen setup: I have two 4K screens and a tiny 1024x768 screen hooked
  up.
- Fractional scaling: enabled, at 125% (see comment below about disabling behavior)
- GNOME version: 42.9 (default)
- Display manager: standard GDM (no
  bells nor whistles)
- X11 is running. Wayland is not available for some reason, [probably this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/2020249), on login
- Nvidia driver version 470.223.02 is running.
- Same behavior whether fractional scaling is enabled or not, scaling scales everything consistently (i.e. higher scaling will make tiny apps OK and everything else HUGE)

Tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419426/110583), but it doesn't quite solve my problem. With fractional scaling *off*, things look a bit more consistent, but then almost everything starts looking tiny. At 200% scale, almost everything looks huge and I have not enough space to work.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating menu size problem]

Comment: Try to change Fonts → Scaling Factor (e.g. 1.40) in `gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: @FedKad, when I do this, fonts appear to scale properly in many apps, e.g. Thunderbird (maybe all GTK apps?), but not in RealVNC Viewer, Tiger VNC, or GIMP.

Comment: [This](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/6832) may be relevant re: GIMP (I have 2.10). Once it (hopefully) starts using GTK in version 3.0, this issue may be solved.